# How can I retrieve the paths of the files that have been uploaded on a FilePond form

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, filepond

***HELP!!!***

I have been struggling trying to find out how to retrieve the paths of the files that have been uploaded on a FilePond form

This is the code that I have so far

```html
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-encode/dist/filepond-plugin-file-encode.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-validate-size/dist/filepond-plugin-file-validate-size.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation/dist/filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.css">
<!--
The classic file input element we'll enhance to a file pond
-->
<!--
The classic file input element we'll enhance
to a file pond, configured with attributes
-->
<input type="file" 
    class="filepond"
    name="filepond" 
    id="DragInput"
    multiple 
    data-max-file-size="9MB"
    data-max-files="3">
    
    <button class="submit_files">Submit</button>
<style>
    /**
 * FilePond Custom Styles
 */
.filepond {
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
 }

 .filepond--root {
     font-size: 11px;
 }

 .filepond--drop-label {
    font-size: 14px;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    color: black;
 }

.filepond--drop-label {
  color: #4c4e53;
}

.filepond--label-action {
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #babdc0;
          text-decoration-color: #babdc0;
}

.filepond--panel-root {
  border-radius: 2em;
  background-color: #edf0f4;
  height: 1em;
}

.filepond--item-panel {
  background-color: #595e68;
}

.filepond--drip-blob {
  background-color: #7f8a9a;
}

</style>
<script>
// We want to preview images, so we register
// the Image Preview plugin, We also register 
// exif orientation (to correct mobile image
// orientation) and size validation, to prevent
// large files from being added
FilePond.registerPlugin(
  FilePondPluginImagePreview,
  FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation,
  FilePondPluginFileValidateSize
);

// Select the file input and use 
// create() to turn it into a pond
FilePond.create(
    document.getElementById('DragInput')
);

$('.filepond').on('FilePond:addfile', function(error, file) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('File Add Error: ' , error);
    return;
  }
  console.log('File Added', file.filename);  
});

var handler = function(fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort) {
  // Custom ajax file upload or local storing here
  
  // Call the error method if something is wrong, should exit after
  error('Error occurred');
  // Call the progress method to update the progress to 100% before calling load
  // Setting computable to false switches the loading indicator to infinite mode
  // (computable, processedSize, totalSize)
  progress(true, 0, 1024);
  // Call the load method when done and pass the returned server file id
  // the load method accepts either a string (id) or an object
  // the unique server file id is used by revert and restore functions
  load('unique-file-id');
  // Abort method so the request can be cancelled by user
  return {
    abort: function() {
      // User tapped abort, cancel ongoing actions here
      // Let FilePond know the request has been cancelled
      abort();
    }
  };
};

</script>

<!-- file upload itself is disabled in this pen -->
```

when the user clicks on the submit button I want the paths of the files that have been uploaded to the FilePond form listed in the console

Thanks,
Arnav

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this is not possible, browsers simply do not expose file path information. https://github.com/pqina/filepond/issues/254#issuecomment-475181033

If you have/find resources that show otherwise I'm happy to adjust the codebase to make file items contain the path info.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means how to get the **server** file paths

Comment: In that case he can return the server path and server file id in the custom process method and then log the path to the console and pass the file id to FilePond